# Time to face the [music]?

Tags: discussion, tags

Is the tag [music](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/music) any use when the tags [itunes](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/itunes), [music.app](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/music.app) and [apple-music](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/apple-music) exist?

Comment: Good title and good question...

Comment: IMO: The tag is too broad.

Comment: I agree that it's too broad. Also, people who know all about iTunes and music listening software don't necessarily know anything about music making. They're two different worlds. In that sense, if the tag "music" can refer to both, it definitely is too broad and therefore a bit misleading. "Music-players" and "music-production" might be options, but as long double word tags, they don't look too neat.

Answer (score 6):

Just pushing this into an answer to get a vote going.

It's time for it to face its final curtain.
No encore, just a swan song.

It's well-covered by the other tags.
It *could* be useful for instance, perhaps for Garage Band or Logic questions, but a quick scroll down the top 50 questions under the tag reveals the other tags would pretty much have covered them all.